# ng-repeat inside popover not work angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, popover

I know that there are a lot of answers on this issue but I tried everything and nothing work. If the element popover work, I can't see any content inside.

My last test :
On my html template :

```
<div class="momentctrl" ng-controller="ButtonsMomentCtrl">
    <div class="btn-group-checkbox">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.daybutton" ng-click="momentChange('daybutton')" type="button" btn-checkbox prevent-default bs-popover items="momentdays", title="Moment of day">Day</button>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="popover_template.html">
          <div ng-repeat='momentday in momentdays'>
              <label>
                  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='momentday.isChecked' ng-change='changeMomentDay(momentday)'/> <span class='ng-binding-advancedsearch'>{{momentday.name}}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

on my controllers :

```
angular.module('my.controllers',['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ButtonsMomentCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.checkModel = {
        allbutton:true,
        nowbutton: false,
        daybutton: false,
        tonightbutton: false
      };
    $scope.momentdays = [
        {
          name: "All",
          id: 0,
          isChecked: true,
          col: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Morning",
          id: 0,
          isChecked: false,
          col: 1
        }, 
        {
          name: "Afternoon",
          id: 1,
          isChecked: false,
          col: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Early evening",
          id: 1,
          isChecked: false,
          col: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Evening",
          id: 1,
          isChecked: false,
          col: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Night",
          id: 1,
          isChecked: false,
          col: 1
        }
      ];
    $scope.momentChange = function(moment){
        console.log("momentChange");
    }
    $scope.changeMomentDay = function(momentDay) {
        console.log("changeMomentDay");
    };
}])
```

on my directives :

```
angular.module('my.directives', [])
.directive('bsPopover', function($compile, $templateCache) {
    console.log("directive bs popover");
        var getTemplate = function () {
            $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
            return $templateCache.get("myPopoverTemplate.html");
        }
        return {
          restrict: "A",
            transclude: true,
            template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var popOverContent;
                var html = getTemplate();
                    popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);
                    console.log("popOverContent = "+popOverContent);                    
                    var options = {
                        content: popOverContent,
                        placement: "bottom",
                        html: true,
                        title: scope.title
                    };
                    element.popover(options);
            },
            scope: {
                title: '@',
                items: '='
            }
        };
});
```

Comment: There are a few things that seem to be missing/wrong in the code you posted. The markup has a comma between attributes. You have 2 modules but neither has a dependency on the other. If you're already using ui.bootstrap, you can achieve this without creating your own directive. There are more problems, but maybe you can post a plunker with what you have so far first.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I updated my ui.bootstrap. I used the last uib-popover-template and now it works perfectly without creating my own directive as you said.